# vertx timeout if async result is failed

Tags: vert.x

I am seeing a timeout in the browser when the server-side service ends in a failed result. Everything works fine if the service call succeeds but it seems as though the browser never receives a response if the call fails.

My service passes a result handler to a DAO containing the following code:

```
final SQLConnection conn = ar.result();
conn.updateWithParams(INSERT_SQL, params, insertAsyncResult -> {

    if (insertAsyncResult.failed()) {
        conn.close();
        resultHandler.handle(ServiceException.fail(1, "TODO"));
    } else {
        resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
    }

});
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. How do I debug what the framework is sending back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to register a ServiceExceptionMessageCodec in an intermediate Verticle, one that was sitting between the browser and the Verticle that was performing the database operation.